# How to build an Aggregation query in symfony with doctrine/mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, aggregation, doctrine-odm

I'm starting out with Symfony and doctrine/mongodb. I'm trying to do an aggregation query, but I get

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "createAggregationBuilder" of class "Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager"

with something like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("/test", name="test")
   */
  public function testAction(Request $request) {
    $builder = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
       ->getManager()
       ->createAggregationQuery('AppBundle:Test');

    var_dump($builder);
  }
}
```

I'm quite frustrated now, since every documentation or stackoverflow questions and answers start with

```
$dm->createAggregationQuery();
```

and I can't find out what `$dm` stands for in this case.

I'd really appreciate some help here.

---

**UPDATE**

I was looking around in the doctrine/mongodb-odm source code and I found that my version is missing the `createAggregationBuilder` function from both the `DocumentRepository.php` and the `DocumentManager.php` file (both located in `/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB` folder.

How can this be?

I mean composer says that I have version 1.1.6, which is the latest release and on the git repo I can cleary see these methods ([DocumentRepository.php](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentRepository.php), [DocumentManager.php](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/315dcabc54c1a5be34ffb806b159ffd60f032827/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentManager.php#L385))

Comment: Perhaps [Doctrine Docs: Aggregation Builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/aggregation-builder.html) can be of assistance. `$dm` is probably a DocumentManager instance in most examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but all the examples there start with:`$builder = $dm->createAggregationBuilder(\Documents\User::class);`
So how can I instantiate that DocumentManager class? I thougth that was what `$this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager()` did. It's probably me, who doesn't know enough of the doctrine way.

Comment: @ccKep it would help a ton if you could please modify my examle code :)

Comment: I never used mongodb, but `$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();` sounds about right. What does it return?

Comment: Yes, it is right as it turned out :) The problem was with my version (as posted in my answer), so the sample code above works just fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me. The problem was that I was using the 1.1.6 version of `doctrine/mongodb-odm` and the Aggregation Builder will only be available in version 1.2. Until than (for anyone being as blind as me), just use the "dev-master" version.
In your `composer.json` modify the `doctrine/mongodb-odm` line to this:

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "dev-master"
}
```

And then run `composer update doctrine/mongodb-odm`.